# continuity and differentiability of function of two variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

Let $f(x,y)$ be
$$f(x,y): \begin{cases} x & \text{for } y = 0\\ x-y^3\sin\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)& \text{for } y \neq 0\end{cases} $$

then check continuity and differentiability  at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
f(x,y) = x - y^3\sin(.) = x + o(x,y)
$$
because $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac {y^3\sin(.)}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} =0$$

- For continuity:
  $$\lim_{(0,0)} f(x,y) = \lim_{(0,0)}x + \lim_{(0,0)}o(x,y) =0
  $$
  then $f$ is continunous in $(0,0)$.
- For differentiability:
  Now identify with the definition of the derivative:
  $$
  f(x,y) = f(0,0) + Df(0,0)\cdot(x,y) + o(x,y)
  $$
  gives you the result:
  $f$ is diffrentiable in in $(0,0)$ and $Df(0,0)\cdot(x,y) = x$.

Comment: its not a home work question, and also i dont know what you have done in your soln. can you tell little bit more? i see that f(0,0) is 0. and $\lim_{x\to 0}\; f(x,y)$ = 0 along x axis and $\lim_{y\to 0}\; f(x,y)$ =0 along y axis, what else do we need for continuity

Comment: sorry, i don't know which concept are u using in ur soln.i was doing by approaching (0,0) along different paths, so i used x axis and y axis as two standard paths.

Comment: i  meant about continuity.

Comment: plz tell about usage of this: $f(x,y) = f(0,0) + Df(0,0)\cdot(x,y) + o(x,y)$  . which text explains this kind of approach?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13640/discussion-between-ketan-and-mookid)

Comment: also plz tell me some source where can i get info about how you wrote f(x,y) in following form: $f(x,y) = x - y^3\sin(.) = x + o(x,y)$